# How can I tell if a variable is numeric and if it's even?

Tags: php

I need my script to tell me if a variable is numeric, and if it is, whether or not it's an even number. My code thus far:

```
        $Numbers = array("1", 2, "three", 4, 5, "six");

        foreach ($Numbers as $Value) {
            if (is_numeric($Value)) {
                if ($Value % 2 == 0) {
                    echo "$Value is numeric, and even";
                } else {
                    echo "$Value is numeric, but not even";
                }
            } else {
                echo "$Value is not numeric";
            }
```

My browser is displaying a blank page.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks like it should work, what error are you getting?

Comment: Please include what output you expect for each element in your array.

Comment: Do you expect `three` and `six` to be interpreted as 'numeric'?

Comment: I'm getting a blank page in my browser, sorry, forgot to add that.

Comment: for "three" and "six", I expect to get the not numeric message

Comment: Ok, just checking - we've had stranger requests here! ;)

Comment: This question is not answerable until you say what results you are expecting.  Do you want `"1"` to return as not numeric or as  numeric and not even. Also are you assuming these are all INT since they do not have decimals? In which case why not ask if they are not integer  rather than not numeric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error.Close foreach loop

```
 $Numbers = array("1", 2, "three", 4, 5, "six");

        foreach ($Numbers as $Value)
        {
            if (is_numeric($Value))
            {
                if ($Value % 2 == 0)
                {
                    echo "$Value is numeric, and even";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "$Value is numeric, but not even";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "$Value is not numeric";
            }
}
```

Comment: How do you know that's not a copy-paste fail? And in any case, syntax errors should be noted in comments, not posted as answers...